# Chai agent does not keep cookie between requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, chai

The following code was working until it recently stopped to keep the cookies between requests. Does anyone have an answer?

Many thanks

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const { after } = require("mocha");

const app = require("app.js");
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;
const agent = chai.request.agent(app);
const userDetails = require("../userDetails");

describe("login test", () => {
 
  it("should return 200", async () => {
    //Log in
    const res = await agent.post("/login").send(userDetails);
    expect(res).to.have.cookie("jwt");

    const res2 = await agent.get("/home");
    
    expect(res2).to.have.cookie("jwt");
    expect(res2).to.have.status(200);

    agent.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example